# How to map json object with typescript Class Object

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am converting my angularjs application to angular6 and i am facing problem to convert json object to typescript object list. in my angular6 application I am using `this.http.get(Url)` to get data from api and my api response as given below

```
[  
       {  
          "offerId":"be88ffe4-f3be-450a-bf5f-39702f841373",
          "expirationDate":"2018-11-09T00:00:00",
          "priority":1,
          "description":"2 monthly installments of $75.34",
          "totalAmount":150.68,
          "futurePayments":[  
             {  
                "id":"9ab0f191-2acc-4795-808f-5ff4ca01ec68",
                "suggestedPaymentDate":"2018-11-08T00:00:00",
                "minDate":"2018-11-08T00:00:00",
                "maxDate":"2018-11-08T00:00:00",
                "suggestedPaymentAmount":75.34,
                "minPaymentAmount":75.34,
                "maxPaymentAmount":75.34
             },
             {  
                "id":"196399d4-893c-4916-85d3-2c134eb8ad73",
                "suggestedPaymentDate":"2018-12-08T00:00:00",
                "minDate":"2018-11-09T00:00:00",
                "maxDate":"2019-01-07T00:00:00",
                "suggestedPaymentAmount":75.34,
                "minPaymentAmount":75.34,
                "maxPaymentAmount":75.34
             }
          ],
          "isSettlement":true,
          "tier":0,
          "code":null
       },
       {  
          "offerId":"7bb19ed1-246c-458c-ae30-8588de87d3ea",
          "expirationDate":"2018-11-09T00:00:00",
          "priority":2,
          "description":"$50 down and 3 monthly installments",
          "totalAmount":150.68,
          "futurePayments":[  
             {  
                "id":"27db97ff-11bc-4faa-b2fa-83252b334961",
                "suggestedPaymentDate":"2018-11-08T00:00:00",
                "minDate":"2018-11-08T00:00:00",
                "maxDate":"2018-11-08T00:00:00",
                "suggestedPaymentAmount":50.0,
                "minPaymentAmount":50.0,
                "maxPaymentAmount":50.0
             },
             {  
                "id":"5149f20b-1e05-4680-bd5c-afc8c332f0fa",
                "suggestedPaymentDate":"2018-12-08T00:00:00",
                "minDate":"2018-11-09T00:00:00",
                "maxDate":"2019-01-07T00:00:00",
                "suggestedPaymentAmount":50.0,
                "minPaymentAmount":100.0,
                "maxPaymentAmount":20.0
             },
             {  
                "id":"bf268808-4870-49f2-ba97-8df749ed048c",
                "suggestedPaymentDate":"2019-01-08T00:00:00",
                "minDate":"2018-12-09T00:00:00",
                "maxDate":"2019-01-15T00:00:00",
                "suggestedPaymentAmount":50.68,
                "minPaymentAmount":100.0,
                "maxPaymentAmount":20.0
             }
          ],
          "isSettlement":false,
          "tier":0,
          "code":null
       },
       {  
          "offerId":"e266f49b-0640-4797-8c43-04e5284b599d",
          "expirationDate":"2018-11-09T00:00:00",
          "priority":1,
          "description":"Settle right now for $100",
          "totalAmount":100.0,
          "futurePayments":[  
             {  
                "id":"5074a769-aae2-452e-b12a-26422972f8c0",
                "suggestedPaymentDate":"2018-11-08T00:00:00",
                "minDate":"2018-11-08T00:00:00",
                "maxDate":"2018-11-08T00:00:00",
                "suggestedPaymentAmount":100.0,
                "minPaymentAmount":100.0,
                "maxPaymentAmount":100.0
             }
          ],
          "isSettlement":true,
          "tier":1,
          "code":null
       }
    ]
```

now i want to convert this JSON object to typescript class object. class structure is given below

```
export class SettlementOffer {

  constructor(offerId: string,
    tier: number,
    priority: number,
    code: string,
    description: string,
    amountNow: number,
    futurePayments: Array<FuturePaymentDto>,
    allowEdit: boolean,
    isSettlement: boolean) {
    this.offerId = offerId;
    this.tier = tier;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
    this.amountNow = amountNow;
    this.futurePayments = futurePayments;
    this.allowEdit = allowEdit;
    this.isSettlement = isSettlement;
  }

  offerId: string;
  tier: number;
  priority: number;
  code: string;
  description: string;
  amountNow: number;
  futurePayments: Array<FuturePaymentDto>;
  allowEdit: boolean;
  isSettlement: boolean;
}

export class FuturePaymentDto {
  constructor(id: string, suggestedPaymentDate: Date, minDate: Date, maxDate: Date, suggestedPaymentAmount: number, minPaymentAmount: number, maxPaymentAmount: number) {
    this.maxPaymentAmount = maxPaymentAmount;
    this.minPaymentAmount = minPaymentAmount;
    this.suggestedPaymentAmount = suggestedPaymentAmount;
    this.maxDate = moment(maxDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10)).toDate();
    this.minDate = moment(minDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10)).toDate();
    this.suggestedPaymentDate = moment(suggestedPaymentDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10)).toDate();
    this.id = id;
  }

  id: string;
  suggestedPaymentDate: Date;
  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;
  suggestedPaymentAmount: number;
  minPaymentAmount: number;
  maxPaymentAmount: number;
}
```

My required output is `Array<SettlementOffer>` for that i am using

```
this.http.get('api/debtor/account/${accountId}/offers').subscribe(response => response.json().map(r => new SettlementOffer(r.offerId, r.tier, r.priority, r.code, r.description, r.amountNow, r.futurePayments, r.allowEdit, r.isSettlement)))
```

The problem that i am facing is to map the json object. i am trying the above code but its not working for me. i need someone help...

My older version code to do this is given below

```
public getOffers(accountId: string): ng.IPromise<Array<SettlementOffer>> {

            return this.$http.get(`/api/debtor/account/${accountId}/offers`)
                .then(data => {

                    return _.map(<any[]>data.data,
                        stuff => {
                            return new SettlementOffer(stuff.offerId,
                                Number(stuff.tier),
                                Number(stuff.priority),
                                stuff.code,
                                stuff.description,
                                Number(stuff.amountNow),
                                _.map(stuff.futurePayments, (data: any) => {
                                    return new FuturePaymentDto(data.id,
                                        new Date(data.suggestedPaymentDate),
                                        new Date(data.minDate),
                                        new Date(data.maxDate),
                                        data.suggestedPaymentAmount,
                                        data.minPaymentAmount,
                                        data.maxPaymentAmount);
                                }),
                                stuff.allowEdit,
                                stuff.isSettlement);
                        });
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'v faced similar issue some time ago and the solution was to threat JSON response as interface and pass it to constructor of object:

```
export interface IJsonResponse {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
}

export class MyClass implements IJsonResponse {

  field1: string;
  field2: string;

  constructor(iIn: IJsonResponse) {
    this.field1 = iIn.field1;
    this.field2 = iIn.field2;
  }

  mapToJson(): IJsonResponse {
    return {
      field1: this.field1,
      field2: this.field2,
    }
  }
}
```

This ensures you the following:

- Field naming will be same in JSON and Class instance
- If you
  add/delete something from your REST service, just add/remove it from
  interface, and TS compiler will auto-complain about missing fields
- By a little additional effort you can create additional methods to transform 
  class object back to interface form

My suggestion to your code is to avoid passing multiple parameters to constructor. Just pass object into it, this will save your time, make it less error-prone and in case you wish to skip single parameters you won't create hell on earth :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that automatically by using tapi.js - don't worry it's very lightweight.

```
npm i -D tapi.js
```

And then

```
let yourObject = new YourClass().fromJSON(jsonData);
```

The conversion works both ways.

Read the documentation [here](https://tapi.js.org) for more details.